Old series about guy scientist and future?
What I remember:
* First episode: Scientist (Second brain in the world (by volume or mass)) found a guy in our days and take him to future. They said that the "first brain" started apocalypses and only this guy can save the world. Very soon we discovered that this "second brain" is responsible for all troubles and "the first brain" found this guy and... I did not watch second episode. So sorry.
* Time machine of "second brain" looks like minivan. But I'm not sure about it.

Dupe of Movie about a guy who goes to a toy dimension.

Even if the answers are the same, the questions are too different.

So I found it via Google Answers =) Thanks for Oleg =)
It was "Josh Kirby Time Warrior"
